# Question regarding np.insert and a Fortran (90 and beyond) equivalent

Tags: python, arrays, fortran

I've been writing a prototype code in Python, for ease, and am ready to convert it to Fortran.  My main problem is that for two of my functions I've been relying on np.insert.  I was curious if there was a Fortran equivalent.  For example, here is one of the functions

```
def GenerateNodes (T):
Nodes = np.array([np.min(T),np.max(T)])
for i in range(np.size(T,axis=0)):
    for j in range(np.size(T,axis=1)):
        for nn in range(np.size(Nodes)):
            if (np.abs(Nodes[nn] - T[i,j]) < tiny):
                break
            elif (Nodes[nn] - T[i,j] > tiny):
                Nodes = np.insert(Nodes,nn,T[i,j])
                break
return Nodes
```

Given that the Nodes array changes size based upon the array T, I'm not sure how to deal with this.  I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: @francescalus the question here asks about NumPy's insert, which I am sure other readers will care about. My answer uses the short allocation on assign, which is also different from the other question you linked to. Could you reopen?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, inserting an element into a Fortran array has much the same set of approaches whether the person wanting to do it knows nothing about Python, is intimately familiar with `np.insert` or any other non-Fortran language.  Using an array constructor and automatic allocation isn't unique to this question so could easily be added as an answer to the linked question, just as mention of linked lists could be added to either.

Comment: @francescalus I agree that inserting an element into a Fortran array is not new, but isn't it also useful to show how np.insert() corresponds to such element insertion in Fortran in detail, if possible? For example, looking at the manual of [np.insert()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), it might correspond to `Nodes = [Nodes( : nn-1 ), T(i,j), Nodes( nn: ) ]` (i.e., inserting T(i,j) _before_ Nodes(nn)), but it might also be necessary to consider the difference of 0- vs 1-based indexing...

Comment: @roygvib, if we have a question on "how do I insert an element into a Fortran array" I personally don't see the value in having specific answers to one asking "how do I convert `np.insert` to Fortran?", or "what is Fortran for C++'s vector::insert?" or "my PostScript program has a push-roll method, Fortran equivalent?". Marking a question as a duplicate is saying "here is the connection between np.insert and `a=[a(1), b, a(2)]`. That said, with three votes to reopen my opinion doesn't matter.

Comment: And, @roygvib, you are correct to say there can be concerns about index offsets (`a=[a(0), 1. a(1)]` changes a from a zero-offset to a one-offset), but those concerns are just as valid in response to the linked question. Duplicates allow us to collect related information in one place and have value for that.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I really do appreciate it.  Sorry if what I asked has already been answered.  Before posting this question I did do some searching..apparently not well enough.

Comment: No apology necessary for asking the question. Even if you missed the association with the linked question before asking, this question now helps the next person to search by pointing directly to that other place. Duplicate questions aren't automatically a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

With `Nodes` an allocatable

```
Nodes = [Nodes(1:nn), T(i, j), Nodes(nn+1, size(Nodes)]
```

will do. This involves many reallocations and can be slow, as it is actually the case for `np.insert`.